# Write ActionScript Value to File Via php

Tags: php, actionscript

I have some XML I've edited in ActionScript that I would like to save locally via php. My php script (called `writeFile.php`) is the following:

```
<?php
  $variable = $_POST['data'];
  $file = "tmp.xml";
  $fh = fopen($file, 'w');
  fwrite($fh, $variable);
  fclose($fh);
  echo "Done!";
?>
```

My ActionScript is the following:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("writeFile.php");
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
vars.data = xml.toXMLString();
request.data = vars;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onComplete);
loader.load(request);
```

However, no file is being created, and thus obviously nothing is being written to it.

Comment: I'm assuming that in you PHP script you have a semi-colon after `$_POST['data']` (you've omitted it in your above example). Additionally, are you sure that the `$_POST` value you are passing to your script has the key value `data`? Are the write permissions of the directory you are trying to write the file to `777`?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575506/how-to-send-mail-with-php-in-actionscript-3) post seemed to indicate that using `vars.data` would create a data key value on the php `POST`.

Comment: What is it that `xml.toXMLString()` is doing - where is that data coming from?

Comment: `xml.toXMLString()` is (for all intents and purposes) just like `xml.toString()`. `xml` is an ActionScript object that contains XML data. So, `xml.toString()` is simply putting that data in a text format.

Comment: When you perform the above scripts, where do you see `Done`? In your browser? Is your script making it that far?

Comment: What happens is that I make it through all of this, and the function `onComplete` (from my `EventListener`) is called, which is just supposed to trace the output of the event. In this case, I thought it would be `Done`, but instead I get back the entire text of the php script.

Comment: Are you testing it locally or on a web server? It sounds like php services are disabled. If you are testing it locally do you have a web server running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have write permission for that directory on the server. And in the onComplete function look for the server response to make sure you're seeing "Done!"